# cannot ping local server from GCP command line - which firewall port to open?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to connect to local server from GCP and do a file transfer to my local machine using scp command. (on the GCP command line prompt_
The system comes out with an error "destination host" is not reachable

Tried pinging from my local machine to GCP server and vice versa, both not reachable.

am wondering some Firewall rules on the GCP side is blocking the traffic.  Would anyone suggest which port to open and how to open it on the GCP side

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you need and what you have tried?

Comment: what I wanted to do is to transfer file to gcp storage bucket from/to using gcp cp command in cloud shell.

Comment: what is the shell command to use, and what is the syntax, for example to copy files from my local machine Dekstop to the cloud gcp storage bucket

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to copy content to/from a GCS bucket.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the network connectivity issue, I would suggest to start the troubleshooting from local and then move to global.

First, try to ping the local IP address on the interface of the host. This should be pingable.

Then ping the default gateway. Then ping the DNS server, either local or Google 8.8.8.8 If it is also working, then check the firewall rules [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) for GCP VM and your local server, that either the ICMP protocol and specified port and IP is allowed or not. Also, check if the network tags [2](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to implement the firewall rule is added to the specified instance or not.

Check if the VM has a service listening on the appropriate port by netstat --listen

Are you able to access the internet without any problems?

With regards to the error, you are getting ‘destination host unreachable,’ It indicates one of two problems: either the local system has no route to the desired destination or a remote router reports that it has no route to the destination.

If the message is simply "Destination Host Unreachable," then there is no route from the local system, and the packets to be sent were never put on the wire.

If the message is "Reply From < IP address >: Destination Host Unreachable," then the routing problem occurred at a remote router, whose address is indicated by the "< IP address >" field.

To address your second concern regarding  transferring a file to GCP storage bucket from a Linux or a Windows instance,  different options are available depending on your workstation OS and the target instance, see the attached document [3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

To copy files from your machine to GCP storage bucket, use the command below:

```
gsutil cp [OPTION]... src_url dst_url     
gsutil cp [OPTION]... src_url... dst_url     
gsutil cp [OPTION]... -I dst_url
```

See the attached link [4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) for more insight.